# What does [$NUM] mean in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I saw some code in the github where people is placing `[$NUM]` in a html file. THere are no javascript tag around the tags. What does it mean and how was it used?

For example:

```
  <div class="input-tooltip">
       [$1100]<br>[$1101].
  </div>
```

OR

```
 <input autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="register-password"
 id="register-password-registerpage" placeholder="[$1114]" />
```

My guess is that this is image of some sort. But how can it be used like this?

Comment: It could be an external JS file targeting the class or input and then looking at the content, if it contained a [$1100] or something it could replace that with something or do some other action.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in HTML. The project might be using some templating tool.

Comment: can you give me an example like how is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var target = $("#register-password-registerpage");
var placeholder = target.attr('placeholder');  

if(placeholder == "[$1114]"){
  console.log("Do something!!, the place holder is "+ placeholder);
  target.css({"background":"orange"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="register-password" id="register-password-registerpage" placeholder="[$1114]" />
 
 

If you wanted to you could use it like this.
```